# How to get React component to detect when state object has changed and re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component: stepA, which obtains a value on submit which is then stored in my redux store as `state.chef_positions.[0].chef_title_id`.

After a user submits StepA, they are instantly directed to StepB. StepB is mounting before stepA's reducer has finished, meaning StepB is loading a incorrect value from the store.

What is the right way to get stepB to re-render when stepA user action has been saved to the server/store, to re-render it's dispatch has finished?

```
class stepA extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(data) {
    this.props.actions.createChefPosition(data);
    this.props.nextStep();
  }

...


class stepB extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const title_id = this.props.chef_positions[0].chef_title_id;
    this.props.dispatch(loadChefTitleSkills(chef_title_id));
  }

  stepB.propTypes = {
    chef_positions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      chef_positions: state.chef_positions,
    };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(stepB);
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything special for this. If you update the state, It will auto re-render. You just need to use react lifecyscle method like `componentWillReceiveProps` to receive the updated props.

Comment: @Ved thanks but I'm a newbie. Can you help me understand how I would update my question to reflect your suggestion thank you

Comment: When you dispatching the action, just check that reducer with corresponding action type is triggered or not. If it is triggered, then just make sure that you are changing the reference of `chef_positions` in your reducer.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: no, still trying to figure it out....

Comment: Share your code of stepA component, your action and reducer. Only then we can tell what's the exact issue. It would be better if you can share codepan.

Comment: @AnApprentice are you doing some asynchronous operation when you call `this.props.actions.createChefPosition(data)` ? As far as I know, redux is synchronous, so it is strange that your component B is rendered before redux terminates its own cycle.

Comment: There's only a single root reducer, so it's not possible for a component to update "before a reducer has finished".  The reducer function will execute to completion before any subscribers are notified.

Answer (score 0):

actually, nothing.

Because of the way Redux is connected to React app is through "first-class object" level (you connect() mapStateToProps to your component), the props in the components are modified to current store state when changes happen at the store.

the only thing you need to do is to re-assign "title_id" with { componentDidUpdate } lifecycle method/use directly "this.props ..." wherever you use title_id/use "useSelector" redux hook.

one other thing, you might cinsider add { mapDispatchToProps } to the connect